# Issue with load balancing in Openshift

Tags: python-3.x, openshift

I have deployed a Python API into OCP with 3 pod replicas. All the incoming requests seem to be going to only one pod while the other 2 being idle all the time.
Configuration I have is :

```
haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout:1800s
haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance:roundrobin 
haproxy.router.openshift.io/disable_cookies:”true”
```

Need help to resolve this issue

Tried changing balance above with leastconn and roundrobin. I don’t see any difference

Comment: "I have deployed a Python API into OCP with 3 pod replicas". what do you mean? a "Deployment" with 3 replicas and a service and and route (or ingress)?

Comment: Yes, My deployment has 3 replicas and one service and a route. Above is the config i have in my template file , i might be missing some ingress config. i don’t have much idea on ingress routing

Comment: what "template file" could you post here the yaml with the`Service`and the`route`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for my issue, Actually i was making the API requests to these pods from another pod in the same namespace. I used the name of service in my url instead of using OCP url in the API call ex: http://ocpservicename:port